# If i have a serverside PHP script which uploads files to another server, what limits it?

Tags: php, file-upload, vimeo

I have a client with a site (built with Kohana framework) which has a chunking file uploader that after upload then posts the file to vimeo for conversion. Problem is that although the file is uploaded successfully to the server, it then errors when sending it on to vimeo. My suspicion is that this post to vimeo is hitting a limit which the first stage chunking uploader avoids.

What settings in the PHP.ini should I be changing to fix this.

The video files are up to 2GB in size.

Update:

In answer to your questions this is a 500 error. I have no more than that due to the fact it only happens on the live server and not on staging and testing. I have been told not to turn on the display_errors for PHP as this will show errors on the live site (which do occur apparently) also this is not my code.

Comment: How are you sending your files to vimeo ?

Comment: Why do you think that problem is related to your PHP.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK everyone, thanks for the answers. Turns out the issue was not with any of the limits but instead was a problem with the file chunking routine and an error reporting the sizes of the chunks sent over to Vimeo. This was only an issue on the live server which was RedHat 4.1 and not on any of the staging or testing machines. A temporary fix has been done by removing the size verification while we find the issue. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to vimeo videos of 500MB for **basic accounts** as seen [here](http://vimeo.com/help/faq#file_limitations). I'm guessing the kind of account that your server is registered with is that, basic, even when your coumputer might be registered with a **plus account**. You'll need to check how to connect with a server using your plus account or restrain your videos size to 500MB.

With more information we would be able to provide better answers.

Comment: Thanks for this Frank. The account is a Vimeo Plus account which is connected correctly and so does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following in your `.htaccess file` you can increase or decrease the value accordingly, by default php sets the max file upload limit to 8M

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: or maybe a simple set_time_limit will solve it...he hasn't told the error..just the problem... =)